# Responsive duration curve in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a **duration curve** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_duration_curve) in Power BI which is **responsive** to the user's selections (slicers). This would help the user to analyse time series for electricity production; for example, for wind power (slicer "type") in France (slicer "area") during the last year (time slicer). Then, the corresponding slicer settings will filter the original data set to only include the user's choice. This chosen subset of the original data should then be ranked descending according to electricity production. Finally, the *ranked* data should be plotted with the rank on the x-axis and the respective production values on the y-axis. The whole process could look like this:
[image]

Here, an example: First, the hourly electricity production:
[image: Time series]

Finally, the corresponding duration curve which I want to display in Power BI. It shows the production time series but sorted descending by their production levels instead of being plotted chronologically:
[image: Duration curve]
The y-axis shows the observed levels and the x-axis their respective duration, e.g. there has only been one hour with >= 59 MW, but approximately 1500 hours with >= 40 MW.

The **question**: How to display the load duration curve *responsive* to the user's selections? As the data includes production levels for different types of production, different regions etc., the user should be able to visualise the corresponding duration curve for whichever type and region etc. she or he is interested in. Therefore, I somehow have to **rank the original data *after* the user's slicer/filter settings have been applied.** This is where I struggle. How can that be done in Power BI?

To facilitate, here two days of (fictive) example data with two areas (1 and 2) and two types of production (1 and 2) which you simply can paste into Power BI as *new calculated table* to have a minimal working example:

```
data = DATATABLE
    (
    "id", INTEGER, 
    "datetimestamp", DATETIME,
    "area", INTEGER,
    "type", INTEGER,
    "point_value", INTEGER,
        {
        {1001,"21-01-01 00:00",1,1,47},
        {1002,"21-01-01 01:00",1,1,51},
        {1003,"21-01-01 02:00",1,1,50},
        {1004,"21-01-01 03:00",1,1,50},
        {1005,"21-01-01 04:00",1,1,51},
        {1006,"21-01-01 05:00",1,1,50},
        {1007,"21-01-01 06:00",1,1,51},
        {1008,"21-01-01 07:00",1,1,51},
        {1009,"21-01-01 08:00",1,1,46},
        {1010,"21-01-01 09:00",1,1,51},
        {1011,"21-01-01 10:00",1,1,46},
        {1012,"21-01-01 11:00",1,1,47},
        {1013,"21-01-01 12:00",1,1,51},
        {1014,"21-01-01 13:00",1,1,48},
        {1015,"21-01-01 14:00",1,1,46},
        {1016,"21-01-01 15:00",1,1,47},
        {1017,"21-01-01 16:00",1,1,48},
        {1018,"21-01-01 17:00",1,1,45},
        {1019,"21-01-01 18:00",1,1,43},
        {1020,"21-01-01 19:00",1,1,45},
        {1021,"21-01-01 20:00",1,1,43},
        {1022,"21-01-01 21:00",1,1,36},
        {1023,"21-01-01 22:00",1,1,36},
        {1024,"21-01-01 23:00",1,1,37},
        {1025,"21-01-02 00:00",1,1,38},
        {1026,"21-01-02 01:00",1,1,36},
        {1027,"21-01-02 02:00",1,1,33},
        {1028,"21-01-02 03:00",1,1,35},
        {1029,"21-01-02 04:00",1,1,42},
        {1030,"21-01-02 05:00",1,1,38},
        {1031,"21-01-02 06:00",1,1,38},
        {1032,"21-01-02 07:00",1,1,37},
        {1033,"21-01-02 08:00",1,1,37},
        {1034,"21-01-02 09:00",1,1,37},
        {1035,"21-01-02 10:00",1,1,35},
        {1036,"21-01-02 11:00",1,1,36},
        {1037,"21-01-02 12:00",1,1,37},
        {1038,"21-01-02 13:00",1,1,37},
        {1039,"21-01-02 14:00",1,1,37},
        {1040,"21-01-02 15:00",1,1,37},
        {1041,"21-01-02 16:00",1,1,40},
        {1042,"21-01-02 17:00",1,1,45},
        {1043,"21-01-02 18:00",1,1,40},
        {1044,"21-01-02 19:00",1,1,37},
        {1045,"21-01-02 20:00",1,1,37},
        {1046,"21-01-02 21:00",1,1,37},
        {1047,"21-01-02 22:00",1,1,37},
        {1048,"21-01-02 23:00",1,1,35},
        {2001,"21-01-01 00:00",1,2,40},
        {2002,"21-01-01 01:00",1,2,41},
        {2003,"21-01-01 02:00",1,2,42},
        {2004,"21-01-01 03:00",1,2,42},
        {2005,"21-01-01 04:00",1,2,42},
        {2006,"21-01-01 05:00",1,2,42},
        {2007,"21-01-01 06:00",1,2,42},
        {2008,"21-01-01 07:00",1,2,43},
        {2009,"21-01-01 08:00",1,2,45},
        {2010,"21-01-01 09:00",1,2,44},
        {2011,"21-01-01 10:00",1,2,43},
        {2012,"21-01-01 11:00",1,2,42},
        {2013,"21-01-01 12:00",1,2,43},
        {2014,"21-01-01 13:00",1,2,44},
        {2015,"21-01-01 14:00",1,2,44},
        {2016,"21-01-01 15:00",1,2,40},
        {2017,"21-01-01 16:00",1,2,40},
        {2018,"21-01-01 17:00",1,2,41},
        {2019,"21-01-01 18:00",1,2,45},
        {2020,"21-01-01 19:00",1,2,44},
        {2021,"21-01-01 20:00",1,2,44},
        {2022,"21-01-01 21:00",1,2,42},
        {2023,"21-01-01 22:00",1,2,42},
        {2024,"21-01-01 23:00",1,2,41},
        {2025,"21-01-02 00:00",1,2,41},
        {2026,"21-01-02 01:00",1,2,42},
        {2027,"21-01-02 02:00",1,2,42},
        {2028,"21-01-02 03:00",1,2,42},
        {2029,"21-01-02 04:00",1,2,41},
        {2030,"21-01-02 05:00",1,2,41},
        {2031,"21-01-02 06:00",1,2,42},
        {2032,"21-01-02 07:00",1,2,42},
        {2033,"21-01-02 08:00",1,2,41},
        {2034,"21-01-02 09:00",1,2,39},
        {2035,"21-01-02 10:00",1,2,41},
        {2036,"21-01-02 11:00",1,2,40},
        {2037,"21-01-02 12:00",1,2,41},
        {2038,"21-01-02 13:00",1,2,42},
        {2039,"21-01-02 14:00",1,2,41},
        {2040,"21-01-02 15:00",1,2,40},
        {2041,"21-01-02 16:00",1,2,39},
        {2042,"21-01-02 17:00",1,2,41},
        {2043,"21-01-02 18:00",1,2,41},
        {2044,"21-01-02 19:00",1,2,42},
        {2045,"21-01-02 20:00",1,2,41},
        {2046,"21-01-02 21:00",1,2,42},
        {2047,"21-01-02 22:00",1,2,41},
        {2048,"21-01-02 23:00",1,2,40},
        {3001,"21-01-01 00:00",2,1,37},
        {3002,"21-01-01 01:00",2,1,38},
        {3003,"21-01-01 02:00",2,1,38},
        {3004,"21-01-01 03:00",2,1,38},
        {3005,"21-01-01 04:00",2,1,39},
        {3006,"21-01-01 05:00",2,1,41},
        {3007,"21-01-01 06:00",2,1,41},
        {3008,"21-01-01 07:00",2,1,43},
        {3009,"21-01-01 08:00",2,1,43},
        {3010,"21-01-01 09:00",2,1,43},
        {3011,"21-01-01 10:00",2,1,45},
        {3012,"21-01-01 11:00",2,1,46},
        {3013,"21-01-01 12:00",2,1,48},
        {3014,"21-01-01 13:00",2,1,48},
        {3015,"21-01-01 14:00",2,1,47},
        {3016,"21-01-01 15:00",2,1,47},
        {3017,"21-01-01 16:00",2,1,47},
        {3018,"21-01-01 17:00",2,1,46},
        {3019,"21-01-01 18:00",2,1,46},
        {3020,"21-01-01 19:00",2,1,46},
        {3021,"21-01-01 20:00",2,1,46},
        {3022,"21-01-01 21:00",2,1,41},
        {3023,"21-01-01 22:00",2,1,41},
        {3024,"21-01-01 23:00",2,1,41},
        {3025,"21-01-02 00:00",2,1,41},
        {3026,"21-01-02 01:00",2,1,40},
        {3027,"21-01-02 02:00",2,1,40},
        {3028,"21-01-02 03:00",2,1,39},
        {3029,"21-01-02 04:00",2,1,39},
        {3030,"21-01-02 05:00",2,1,41},
        {3031,"21-01-02 06:00",2,1,40},
        {3032,"21-01-02 07:00",2,1,40},
        {3033,"21-01-02 08:00",2,1,40},
        {3034,"21-01-02 09:00",2,1,42},
        {3035,"21-01-02 10:00",2,1,41},
        {3036,"21-01-02 11:00",2,1,41},
        {3037,"21-01-02 12:00",2,1,41},
        {3038,"21-01-02 13:00",2,1,43},
        {3039,"21-01-02 14:00",2,1,44},
        {3040,"21-01-02 15:00",2,1,45},
        {3041,"21-01-02 16:00",2,1,46},
        {3042,"21-01-02 17:00",2,1,47},
        {3043,"21-01-02 18:00",2,1,47},
        {3044,"21-01-02 19:00",2,1,47},
        {3045,"21-01-02 20:00",2,1,46},
        {3046,"21-01-02 21:00",2,1,43},
        {3047,"21-01-02 22:00",2,1,41},
        {3048,"21-01-02 23:00",2,1,40},
        {4001,"21-01-01 00:00",2,2,37},
        {4002,"21-01-01 01:00",2,2,33},
        {4003,"21-01-01 02:00",2,2,35},
        {4004,"21-01-01 03:00",2,2,33},
        {4005,"21-01-01 04:00",2,2,35},
        {4006,"21-01-01 05:00",2,2,25},
        {4007,"21-01-01 06:00",2,2,27},
        {4008,"21-01-01 07:00",2,2,30},
        {4009,"21-01-01 08:00",2,2,35},
        {4010,"21-01-01 09:00",2,2,35},
        {4011,"21-01-01 10:00",2,2,32},
        {4012,"21-01-01 11:00",2,2,37},
        {4013,"21-01-01 12:00",2,2,37},
        {4014,"21-01-01 13:00",2,2,35},
        {4015,"21-01-01 14:00",2,2,37},
        {4016,"21-01-01 15:00",2,2,36},
        {4017,"21-01-01 16:00",2,2,33},
        {4018,"21-01-01 17:00",2,2,30},
        {4019,"21-01-01 18:00",2,2,31},
        {4020,"21-01-01 19:00",2,2,28},
        {4021,"21-01-01 20:00",2,2,25},
        {4022,"21-01-01 21:00",2,2,22},
        {4023,"21-01-01 22:00",2,2,24},
        {4024,"21-01-01 23:00",2,2,26},
        {4025,"21-01-02 00:00",2,2,24},
        {4026,"21-01-02 01:00",2,2,23},
        {4027,"21-01-02 02:00",2,2,26},
        {4028,"21-01-02 03:00",2,2,25},
        {4029,"21-01-02 04:00",2,2,25},
        {4030,"21-01-02 05:00",2,2,26},
        {4031,"21-01-02 06:00",2,2,30},
        {4032,"21-01-02 07:00",2,2,26},
        {4033,"21-01-02 08:00",2,2,21},
        {4034,"21-01-02 09:00",2,2,23},
        {4035,"21-01-02 10:00",2,2,32},
        {4036,"21-01-02 11:00",2,2,25},
        {4037,"21-01-02 12:00",2,2,25},
        {4038,"21-01-02 13:00",2,2,25},
        {4039,"21-01-02 14:00",2,2,26},
        {4040,"21-01-02 15:00",2,2,26},
        {4041,"21-01-02 16:00",2,2,25},
        {4042,"21-01-02 17:00",2,2,26},
        {4043,"21-01-02 18:00",2,2,26},
        {4044,"21-01-02 19:00",2,2,25},
        {4045,"21-01-02 20:00",2,2,25},
        {4046,"21-01-02 21:00",2,2,24},
        {4047,"21-01-02 22:00",2,2,23},
        {4048,"21-01-02 23:00",2,2,24}
        }
    )
```

**Thanks** for your help, all hints are welcome!

Comment: your question lack clarity, can you state you issues more clearly

Comment: @RF1991: I adjusted the description and hope it became clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is very interesting and I have been meaning to answer it sooner! If a line chart is required, you can do the following:

- Add a `GENERATESERIES` table of the number of hours you need in your analysis, for example (edited based on your comment):

```
Hours = GENERATESERIES(0, DISTINCTCOUNT(data[datetimestamp]), 1)
```

- Add the following measure to calculate your load curve:

```
Load Curve := 
VAR _hrs = SELECTEDVALUE ( Hours[Value] )
VAR _tbl = 
    SUMMARIZE( 
        data , 
        data[datetimestamp] ,
        "Power", SUM ( data[point_value] )
    )
VAR _power_tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        SUMMARIZE ( 
            _tbl , 
            [Power]
        ), 
        "Count" ,
        VAR _val = [Power]
        RETURN 
        COUNTROWS ( 
            FILTER ( 
                _tbl , 
                [Power] >= _val 
            )
        )
    )

RETURN
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _power_tbl , [Count] = _hrs ) , 
    [Power]
)
```

Use this measure with your `Hours` table column (by default called `Value`) to establish your dynamic load curve:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! One might substitute `Hours = GENERATESERIES(0, 1000, 1)` by `Hours = GENERATESERIES(0, numberOfHours, 1)` where `numberOfHours = DISTINCTCOUNT(data[datetimestamp])` to get the necessary number of hours. But any large number seems to work fine, too.

Comment: There is one more thing I would like to ask: Plotting the duration curves for different types or areas is really good. To illustrate "smoothing effects" when combining different renewable energy sources such as hydropower and wind, I would also like Power BI to plot the duration curve for the sum of the selected types or areas. This was part of an earlier version of this question, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70997174/12. Do you have an idea here, too? That would be great, thanks!

Comment: See the new formula - based on your comment I believe my previous solution was incorrect, so this new code should do what you want. Now you can select arbitrary types and areas and get the "summed" load duration curve in the visualisation.